# Are there any popular open source projects written in C++?

Tags: c++, open-source

I've read the source code of a few popular open source projects like apache, nginx...

All of them are written in C, is there one written in C++?

It should be run-able program, not framework...

Comment: WebKit, Boost, ... also check the project searches on sourceforge and code.google. Keep in mind though that SO is about specific programming questions, not polling.

Comment: There are some people from 1980s and 1990s who claim that C is superior, but most of people now use C++, not very old C ;)

Comment: R__ welcome to SO. This is a Q&A site looking for concrete answers, not a forum. Please figure out how to rephrase your question and ask again.

Comment: @0A0D ,can you recommend a forum for such problems?

Comment: @R__: You can try our other Q&A site programmers.stackexchange.com. However, the purpose of any Q&A site is to produce high quality questions and answers. I am not sure your question will be accepted at any of the SE sites, but you can try programmers.

Comment: Don't ask again if the answer will be "yeah, lots. And you can find them online". If you're looking for excellent sources to learn from, you might have a look at previous questions first, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109684/what-are-some-examples-of-exceptional-c-open-source-code) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793/well-written-open-source-projects-for-learning) or any of the questions you will find under "Related" on the right. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

KDE

and up, to 30 characters and beyond.

Comment: Is it something that can be run by commands like `./entry` ?

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla Firefox is written (mainly) in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this list : http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/applications.html

Comment: Most in the list are NOT open source.

Comment: I know, but it's still the quickest way to find large open-source C++ projects.